# What should I study for designing card game?

Tags: game-design

I need to design a point-based card game to teach something in the classroom.

Which mathematical area discusses the principles of card games?

Is it "Game Theory"?

What I understood is, game theory analyzes existing games such as Poker and so on. Does it give clues to designing new games?

It would be helpful if someone supplies me with any book for getting started with desiugning card games.

Comment: Eric Lang once told me that the #1 thing he did to prepare for his career was to *play a lot of games*. So obviously that's a good start. I would argue that game theory should come way after you have immersed yourself in the modern tabletop (not RPG) scene, and studied probability/combinatorics.

Comment: *The Complete Kobold Guide to Game Design* would be my suggesting for an aspiring game designer.